Unable to create the online endpoint
I am trying to create a endpoint inference to deploy a model into the azure machine learinig workspace. I used below cli command to deploy the model but its failing with following error
(SubscriptionNotRegistered) Resource provider [N/A] isn't registered with Subscription [N/A]. Please see troubleshooting guide, available here: https://aka.ms/register-resource-provider
Code: SubscriptionNotRegistered
Message: Resource provider [N/A] isn't registered with Subscription [N/A]. Please see troubleshooting guide,

i have already registered Microsoft.MachineLearningServices
below is the yml template and cli used to create the endpoint
endpoint.yml

$schema: https://azuremlschemas.azureedge.net/latest/onlineEndpoint.schema.json
name: bird-pytorch-endpoint-v1
auth_mode: key


cli command
az ml online-endpoint create --file endpoint.yml --resource-group myresourcepsrg --workspace-name azuremlws

below is the current user access details
Principal                                                             Role    Scope
--------------------------------------------------------------------  ------  ---------------------------------------------------
azure_hari3_gmail.com#EXT#@azure_hari3gmail102.onmicrosoft.com  Owner   /subscriptions/75272772727-828

Now i am getting below error

(SubscriptionNotRegistered) Resource provider [N/A] isn't registered with Subscription [N/A]. Please see troubleshooting guide, available here: https://aka.ms/register-resource-provider
Code: SubscriptionNotRegistered
Message: Resource provider [N/A] isn't registered with Subscription [N/A]. Please see troubleshooting guide, available here: https://aka.ms/register-resource-provider

Any resolution to this?

Refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/2085484/how-to-identify-unregistered-service-provider make sure you register your resource.

Check the below answer.


Unable to create the online endpoint

Initially, I also got the same error in my environment, When I try to create online endpoint.
Error:
az ml online-endpoint create --file endpoint.yml" --resource-group venkatesan-rg --workspace-name venkatspace4
az : ERROR: (SubscriptionNotRegistered) Resource provider [N/A] isn't registered with Subscription [N/A]. Please see troubleshooting guide, available here: https://aka.ms/register-resource-provider
At line:1 char:1
+ az ml online-endpoint create --file "C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\endp ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (ERROR: (Subscri...source-provider:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
Code: SubscriptionNotRegistered
Message: Resource provider [N/A] isn't registered with Subscription [N/A]. Please see troubleshooting guide, available here: https://aka.ms/register-resource-provider


To resolve the above error, you need register both Microsoft.Cdn and Microsoft.PolicyInsights in your Azure Subscription.
Portal:
Portal-> < Your-Subscription> -> Resource providers -> search Microsoft.Cdn and Microsoft.PolicyInsights -> Register.

After registering both resource providers, I can be able to create the online ml endpoint using the same command.
Command and output:
PS C:\Users\xxx> az ml online-endpoint create --file "endpoint.yml" --resource-group "venkatesan-rg" --workspace-name "venkatspace4"
{
  "auth_mode": "key",
  "id": "/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/venkatesan-rg/providers/Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/venkatspace4/onlineEndpoints/bird-pytorch-endpoint-v1",
  "identity": {
    "principal_id": "xxx",
    "tenant_id": "9xxx",
    "type": "system_assigned"
  },
  "kind": "Managed",
  "location": "eastus",
  "mirror_traffic": {},
  "name": "bird-pytorch-endpoint-v1",
  "openapi_uri": "https://bird-pytorch-endpoint-v1.eastus.inference.ml.azure.com/swagger.json",
  "properties": {
    "AzureAsyncOperationUri": "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/locations/eastus/mfeOperationsStatus/xxxx?api-version=2022-02-01-preview",
    "azureml.onlineendpointid": "/subscriptions/xxx/resourcegroups/venkatesan-rg/providers/microsoft.machinelearningservices/workspaces/venkatspace4/onlineendpoints/bi
rd-pytorch-endpoint-v1",
    "createdAt": "2024-10-17T10:14:22.250637+0000",
    "createdBy": "xxxx",
    "lastModifiedAt": "2024-10-17T10:14:22.250637+0000"
  },
  "provisioning_state": "Succeeded",
  "public_network_access": "enabled",
  "resourceGroup": "venkatesan-rg",
  "scoring_uri": "https://bird-pytorch-endpoint-v1.eastus.inference.ml.azure.com/score",
  "tags": {},
  "traffic": {}
}

Portal:

